# Appending data from different tables - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables `Job description` and `Candidate`.
Each job description can be related to n candidates. The candidates are obtained from different sources(a, b, c d) - `candidate.source`.

I want a single query to list me the JD ids, with count of candidates for each source for each JD, as shown below:

```
JD id | candidate name | count of candidates - source a | count of candidates - source b | count of candidates - source | c..............
```

Comment: Does getting the Count of sources, grouped by candidate name not work? Also it seems odd you want a count of candidates and a (random?) candidate name in the same row. It would help if you can add in flat text the table structures with sample data and the expected result set with sample data. You can also use http://sqlfiddle.com/ if you want to add your current SQL you have tried so far.

Comment: candidate name is a mistake - regret the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the query as a template:

```
select 
JobDescriptionName, 
SUM(ACount) CountOfCandidatesOfA ,  
SUM(BCount) CountOfCandidatesOfB, 
SUM(CCount) CountOfCandidatesOfC ,  
SUM(DCount) CountOfCandidatesOfD 
from 
 ( select JobDescriptionID, (CASE WHEN Source = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACount, 
            (CASE WHEN Source = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BCount, 
            (CASE WHEN Source = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CCount, 
            (CASE WHEN Source = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DCount 
            from Candidate) AS DerivedCandidate

 inner join JobDescription ON JobDescription.JobDescriptionID = DerivedCandidate.JobDescriptionID group by JobDescriptionID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already an accepted answer but in the effort of learning myself more about SQL here is an alternative way applying the `case` directly in the initial select without the sub-select:

```
Select 
  jd.id,
  jd.name, 
  sum(case when c.source = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as sourceA,
  sum(case when c.source = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as sourceB,
  sum(case when c.source = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) as sourceC,
  sum(case when c.source = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) as sourceD
from JobDescription as jd
join Candidate as c on c.jobId = jd.id
group by jd.id, jd.name
```

---

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7b69/4)

---

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JD id, COUNT(Candidate), source
FROM table1
GROUP BY JD id,source
```

Comment: This doesn't produce a column for each source in the output.